# jQuery disable submit button if text box contains these variables

Tags: textbox, submit, keyup

How I can strip out the variables listed below from within a textbox (input) that if a user tries to type a URL i.e these variables:
"http://"
"www."
".com"
".co.uk"

If any of the variables above exist in the textbox on keyup the submit button gets disabled or/and it removes/strips out the variables above.

Is this possible? I've tried doing it using Charcodes, but I face the problem that I would like the user to still use '.; (full-stops) etc

Can somebody help?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: If a user types in the textbox:
"I managed to find a solution at www.domain.com, hope you find it useful"

The submit button gets disabled because they've typed "www." and ".com" in the text box.

Comment: try textbox on blur event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2kYK/8/)

```
$("#myinput").keyup(function() 
   {

    var a = ["http://", "www.", ".com", ".co.uk"]; //Add the substrings
    a.forEach(function(k)
    {
       if($("#myinput").attr("value").indexOf(k) > -1)
       {
           alert('Found!'); //Do something
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
            return false;
       }
    });

});
```

Every time the user types a char, it checks for the string in array a. If the substring is found, it popups an alert message.
Using blur it will check for the string only when the user go outs of the input box (its more efficient using blur, but you can use this way if you want to check few strings and the input value is not too long).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've managed to solve my issue. Instead of an alert I've added $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#textboxId").blur(function (event) {
 var text = event.target.val();
 if(text.contains("www")) {
  $("submitBtnId").prop('disabled', true);
 }
});
```